# How to use HtmlTidy in a C# forms application?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, htmltidy

I am coding a C# Windows Forms application and am using `Html Agility Pack` to generate html code.

I am wanting to use `HtmlTidy` to tidy up the generated html. Can someone please inform me of how to correctly do this in .NET. I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

I have tried both the 32 and 64 bit versions of the file at this resource link:
https://github.com/markbeaton/TidyManaged

When adding a reference to this library, I am getting the following error:
[image]

I have also tried the following via NuGet:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/TidyNetPortable/1.0.0
https://www.nuget.org/packages/TidyManaged/1.0.0

After adding these above packages, I am not sure on how to use the `HtmlTidy` features.

I have also looked at many resources online and have seen that many of these are many years old.

What is the best `HTMLTidy` library to use in a C# Windows Forms application? Is there an easy library to install via NuGet that will work with minimal or no hassle at all?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you added a reference to the assembly into your project?

Comment: I am getting the above error after adding a reference to the assembly when pressing the ok button.